# how do I count in aggregation in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have list of collection like this :

```
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1000'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'bob', value: true, shrotDate : '1001'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'bob', value: false, shrotDate : '1001'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'bob', value: true, shrotDate : '1003'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1004'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: false, shrotDate : '1004'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1004'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: false, shrotDate : '1005'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1006'}**strong text**
```

I want to aggregation so, each user will have a counter that counts the number of values that was true, but for each day only once, meaning that if I have a user that has vlue = true two times, but in the same day, it only count 1.
for example:

```
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1004'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: false, shrotDate : '1004'}
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', value: true, shrotDate : '1004'}
```

will added only 1 to the counter because it is the same day.

This is what I have, but it counts multiple time for each day.

```
db.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$name", count:{$sum:1}}},
    ("$match" : {"value" : true}
])
```

so after the aggregation I will have a list like this:

```
    {
   "user" : john,
   "count" : 3
    },
    {
   "user" : bob,
   "count" : 2
    },
```

Thanks.

---

***Answer!***

so I fund the answer to my own question.

```
db.getCollection().aggregate(
[
    {$match: {"value": "true"}},
    {$group: {_id: {u: "$name", d: "$shortDate"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id.u", c: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {c: -1}},
]
)
```

what I did is first find all the days that the value was true and then group it again by the ID only.

Comment: You really should try to complete a minimum working example to show us so that we can more effectively help. If you don't know where to start the mongoDB api will have some examples on how to do something once per day

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact answer but I can help a little.

You can use the `$sum` accumulator aggregation operator as documented here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

And also the `$cond` conditionnal aggregation operator, here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

In the `$group` stage, add a `count` property with `{ $sum: 1 }` which means your increment by one for each user in the group.

Now you want to increment only if a condition is verified, you may use `$cond` here. According to the documentation: `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }` so it will be `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, 1, 0 ] }`

Example (according your collection's name is `users`, you may need to change for your model):

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: $name,
           count: {
               $sum: { "$cond": [ <boolean-expression>,  1, 0 ] }
           }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

I hope it'll help!